# Bigcommerce add processing fee on checkout

Tags: checkout, bigcommerce

I am in the process of adding an additional credit card processing fee of 2.5% across the entire bill upon check out in a bigcommerce store. My question is: Can I manipulate the grand total as it seems I cannot change it or is there any other way?. Also would adding a line items work? Or if you have any other idea please let me know. There is not much information that is found in BC site

Answer (score 1):

So you actually have a couple of no code options in setting this up!

You could use the native [Handling Fee](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Handling-Fees) (percent or flat rate) to add a fee to the shipping, which I would assume you'd do more than 2.5% if you chose this route. Or you can look at [creating a custom tax](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/article/Tax-Overview) to add to the checkout.

We do have an [Idea in our Ideas Portal](https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/ideas#087130000003Ec1AAE) that I invite you to review that is to support transaction fees on the order. If you are in support of this idea, please upvote it to relay that feedback to our Product teams! :)

Comment: Thanks for your response. However I think the handling fee doesn't work as it will only charge the  % on the shipping only and we want the entire bill. Also the custom tax, i am not sure if it works as we already have a existing tax app implemented.  Also it seems I cannot access ideas portal, any alternative?

Comment: To access the Ideas portal, you would need to create a Community account.